# Embed a UISlider as item in an UIActionsheet in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, slider

I would like to embed a `UISlider` as item in an `UIActionsheet` In iOS7.

The UIActionsheet also contains 3 regular buttons, while the slider is the 1st item above those buttons.
The value of the slider shall be given back to the calling object, from which the Actionsheet is triggered.

Any ideas how to achieve this?